# What could cause a QuerySyntaxException: [Entity] is not mapped, although the entity has been bound?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I wonder why I get `QuerySyntaxException: [Entity] is not mapped`, although Hibernate is logging

```
INFO Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.0-Final
...
INFO Binding entity from annotated class: products.model.ProductGroup
INFO Bind entity products.model.ProductGroup on table GRP
...
INFO table found: GRP
INFO columns: [grp, name, top]
```

The entity class looks like

```
@Entity(name="GRP")
public class ProductGroup implements IdentifiableEntity {

    @Id
    private String grp;
    private String name;
    private String top;

    ...
}
```

The error is thrown at this line:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select g from ProductGroup g");
```

It is all JPA, no Hibernate API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Entity(name) sets the internal name of the entity for JPA. Try removing that statement and work with an @Table(name = "GRP")

If that doesn't work, please post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: That resolved it. Thank you! But there error message and the logging statements are a bit misleading, aren't they?

Comment: It seems to me that the exception is a bit generic, but I can understand why they don't want to map an error message for each case. It's a bit of a pitfall, but they could indeed just signal that you have an incorrect configuration.